# How to get parent's most viewed child in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, parent-child

I have a catalogue categories  with items. The main catalogue page must display the list of categories with the amount of items inside of each category, and the "preview" picture must be the most viewed item of that same category.

**catalogue_cat**

- id_cat
- name

**catalogue_item**

- id_item
- name
- picture_url
- views (INT)

  SELECT catalogue_cat.id_cat, catalogue_cat.name, COUNT(catalogue_item.id_item) AS q
  FROM catalogue_cat
  LEFT JOIN catalogue_item ON catalogue_item.id_cat = catalogue_cat.id_cat
  GROUP BY catalogue_cat.id_cat ORDER BY catalogue_cat.name

That only brings me the list of categories with the item count. I still need the picture of the most viewed item of each category. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already doing a `group by`, so the best approach is the `substring_index()`/`group by` approach:

```
SELECT c.id_cat, c.name, COUNT(i.id_item) AS q,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(i.url ORDER BY i.views DESC), ',', 1) as MostViewedURL
FROM catalogue_cat c LEFT JOIN
     catalogue_item ci
     ON i.id_cat = c.id_cat
GROUP BY c.id_cat
ORDER BY c.name;
```

Note that this assumes that the URL's don't have commas in them.  If they do, you will need to find another separator character.

Comment: The picture_url is really a filename, i add the complete URL that points to that filename in php. I'm trying your approach right now...